# How to create a view that outputs an HTML list?

Tags: views, 8, theming

[image]

I want to create a menu like this so I create a new view and I make some change in format (html list) and fields but I can not do it like the original one !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to group the rows by your "File Usage: Entity Label (Assurance particuliers)" field.

To do that go to the "HTML List" settings and select that field in the dropdown of the "Grouping field Nr.1" setting.

You will then want to hide the field from display, and you do that in the field's own settings, "Exclude from display".

You can also add "File Usage: Entity Label (Assurance entreprises)" and "File Usage: Entity Label (Assurance de personnes)" fields and set them as Grouping fields Nr.2 and Nr.3 in the HTML List settings to give you the second and third columns in your list. Don't forget to hide these also!

I hope this helps.